# Bash how to add single quotes in command

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to run this command inside jenkins.

```
sh 'docker run --name container_name -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:8.0 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci --sql-mode='''
```

but the
`--sql-mode='''` comes out as `--sql-mode='` and it's failing because of that. How to make it so it comes out as `--sql-mode='''` after compiling a jenkinsfile?

This is the full error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property '' on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:469)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:377)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:379)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:62)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor518.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:177)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:166)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the jenkins log when it fails:

```
[Pipeline] sh
11:33:29  + docker run --name mysql_inventory -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:8.0 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci --sql-mode=
11:33:29  6128f8dacd51cd7650db8dfc23e7e78311fd41b3c5e3c2e0bbcc81b9836d5afd
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
Stage "Build" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Archive)
Stage "Archive" skipped due to earlier failure
```

It seems the docker container is created from the Jenkins log but have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: `and it's failing` What is the exact full verbatim error message? Please post jenkins logs. _Why_ do you think it "comes out as", how do you check that? See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help .

Comment: This is the error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property '' on null object
I'm saying it's failing on this because the next steps are not running because of previous error. 

`11:28:48  + docker run --name mysql_inventory -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:8.0 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci --sql-mode=
11:28:48  fd294bd2575c2c3aa12a8403cc69251b7884d16dd2ce2f69eec62ad48604f9a3
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
Stage "Build" skipped due to earlier failure(s)`

Comment: Please post _full_ verbatim error message _into the question_. What is it saying exactly? How do you know that this messages means that it "comes out as --sql-mode='"? `--sql-mode= 11:28:48` this part suggests that it "doesn't come out".

Comment: The simple fix is to pass double quotes for the inner quotes, like `--sql-mode=""`. Even simpler, just omit the empty string; `--sql-mode=`

Comment: In the code you posted, the last argument which `docker` receives is just a `--sql-mode='`, i.e. without anything to the right of the equal sign. If this is not what you want to pass to _docker_, please specify which string `docker` should see as its last argument. I don't think you really send three single quotes to _docker_ with this argument.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess you are inside single quotes. Consider reading both https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html .

I will guess the error comes becuase of odd syntax error string construct in groovy.

```
def example = '.....stuff.... ' ''
# two strings side by side - what to do with them in groovy?
def valid = 'stuff' + ''
# you could add two strings, but side by side is invalid.
```

Just remove the quotes, empty quotes are empty in shell anyway.

```
sh 'docker run --name container_name -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:8.0 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci --sql-mode='
```

You can use double quotes or use triped-quoted string from groovy.

```
sh 'docker run --name container_name -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:8.0 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci --sql-mode=""'
```

Note that first Jenkins does the variable expansion and then shell does variable expansion, and they are completely separate expansion with different rules.